# matplotlib: plt.show() shows three figures

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using `matplotlib` to plot two graphs coming from some analysis on a set of emails. 
Here is the script that should show two figures and instead it actually show three. How can I solve this bug?

```
# Show the distribution of emails over the years
ax = emails_df.groupby(emails_df['Date'].dt.year)['content'].count().plot()
ax.set_xlabel('Year', fontsize=18)
ax.set_ylabel('N emails', fontsize=18)

f1 = plt.figure()

# Show the distribution of emails over a week
ax = emails_df.groupby(emails_df['Date'].dt.dayofweek)['content'].count().plot()
ax.set_xlabel('Day of week', fontsize=18)
ax.set_ylabel('N emails', fontsize=18)

f2 = plt.figure()

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The figure calls should come before the plots, not after. With your code, you'll have  a *blank* figure with the last `plt.figure` call:

```
# figure 1
ax = emails_df.groupby(emails_df['Date'].dt.year)['content'].count().plot()
...

# figure 2
f1 = plt.figure()
...

# figure 3
f2 = plt.figure()

plt.show()
```

Fix this by moving the `plt.figure` calls before the preceding `plot` call.